# cannot find my custom js file

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

I have created under app/code/vendor/theme/view/frontend/layout/defaul.xml an file called `default.xml` and i have following content in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <head>
        <!-- Add js using link tag-->
        <script src="js/main.js"/>
   </head>
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Steiner\Josef\Block\Mage" template="Steiner_Josef::contact_right.phtml"></block>
</referenceContainer>
</page>
```

It shows me the PHTML file correctly but the js/main.js it cant be found.
I put the js file under `app/code/vendor/theme/web/js/main.js` and I have the following content:

```
    define(["jquery"], function($) {
    "use strict";

    // Here your custom code...
    console.log("Hola");
  });
```

after clearing cache, flush, etc. nothing seems to work what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You have to add code in default_head_blocks.xml, Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to in

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!-- Add local resources -->
        <link src="js/main.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/js/main.js

```
require(['jquery'], function($){ 
    /* Code... */ 
    console.log("Hola");
})
```

and run the below commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Clear the cache and check.

Comment: seems not to work, maybe i have forgot some further steps , do you know any good resource to research?

Comment: I have updated my answer, Please check

Comment: i will check it out tomorrow in the morning

Answer (score 0):

The best way to add `js` file is with **requirejs**

Here is a full example.

Supposing your js file is: `myfile.js`

> 1. app/design/frontend/GWtheme/gw/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            myscript: 'js/myfile'
        }
    }
};
```

> 2. app/design/frontend/GWtheme/gw/web/js/myfile.js

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
   "use strict";
       return function myscript()
       {
           alert("OKKKK!");
       }
});
```

Now we have to load our js in phtml, supposing we want to call it in `yourfile.phtml`

> 3. app/design/frontend/GWtheme/gw/Magento_Theme/templates/{yourfile}.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'myscript'], function($, myscript) {
        myscript();
    });
</script>
```

If you want to load that js in all pages, you just have to do this:

> 4. app/design/frontend/GWtheme/gw/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    deps: [
        'js/myfile.js'
    ],
};
```

**Important:** don't forget to :

- clean the cache
- clean `var/view_preprocessed` **CONTENT**
- clean `pub/static` **CONTENT**
- deploy the static content = `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: what to do if i have the `Mismatched anonymous define() module` error?

Comment: You have encountered this error in my solution ?

Comment: yea, i got this error never before

Comment: Try step 1, 2, 3 without the 4, don't forget the `important` step